# Solution verification: Finding orbit and stabelizer of group $G=\mathbb R_{>0}$ action on $X=\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find orbits and stabelizer of group $G=\mathbb R_{>0}$ action on $X=\mathbb R$ denoted by $g(x)=g\cdot x$.

So this was a quiz question, and I wanna see if my solution was correct.

$orb_G(x)=\{g\in G: gx\}\subseteq X$

So since field is closed under multiplication, for every $g \in G$ we will get that $gx \in X$, so that means $orb_G(x)=\mathbb R_{>0}$

Stabelizer is defined as all $g \in G: gx=x$, and in that case $g=1$.

So there's only one orbit with stabilizer = 1.

I'm not confident with these subjects, so I'm not sure I solved it correctly.

Thank you in advance for any input you can share.

Comment: And what is $orb_G(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working it out, let me give you some smaller questions to try to answer.  Consider the two elements $1$ and $-1$ in $X = \mathbb{R}$.  Is there a $g \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ such that $-1 = g 1$?  What does that tell you about the orbits?

Once you understand that, picture the real line.  Think about what happens to an element of $\mathbb{R}$ when it is multiplied by an element of $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.  A single orbit is obtained by starting with one element $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and then considering all possible elements of the form $g x$ for $g \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.  If you take $x = 1$, what is its orbit?  What if you take $x = -1$?  Are there any other orbits left?

(These questions will help you understand orbits.  After you understand orbits, you'll be better equipped to handle stabilizers.)